# Can matplotlib plot cause sklearn's PCA.fit_transform function to fail?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, pycharm

In code snippet one, if I run it in my Pycharm console as a complete block of code a single time, it will run completely and successfully print the PCA output twice.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1, 2 , 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
xy = np.array([x, y]).T
xy_pca = PCA(n_components=1).fit_transform(xy)
print(xy_pca)
ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(111)
xy_pca_2 = PCA(n_components=1).fit_transform(xy)
print(xy_pca_2)
```

However, if I run that complete block of code again, I get "nan's" as the output of the first print statement, but a correct output from the second print statement.
Also if I start over and use the python console to run that block of code line by line, I get a correct output on the first print statement, but "nan's" from the second print statement.

This leads me to believe that matplotlib functionality somehow interferes with a state necessary to successfully run sklearn's PCA.fit_transform function. Or something weird is happening in the console state.

But this is not the end of the story. With this second block of code below, whether it is run as a complete block or line by line from the Python console, it will never fail. The only difference is that the x and y arrays are one item shorter each. This should not affect either the matplotlib or sklearn functionality, but somehow it is making a difference.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1, 2 , 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
y = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
xy = np.array([x, y]).T
xy_pca = PCA(n_components=1).fit_transform(xy)
print(xy_pca)
ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(111)
plt.show()
xy_pca_2 = PCA(n_components=1).fit_transform(xy)
print(xy_pca_2)
```

System config:

- Python 3.7.8
- PyCharm 2020.2 (Community Edition)
  Build #PC-202.6397.98, built on July 28, 2020
  Runtime version 11.0.7+10-b944.20 amd64
  VM OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
  Windows 10 10.0
  GC ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
  Memory 2014M
  Cores 4
- matplotlib 3.3.1
- sklearn 0.23.2

Comment: I cant reproduce what you said..

Comment: Thanks for trying. One of my coworkers cannot reproduce it, and another can reproduce it sometimes and not others.